# Looking for module in wrong path in Grunt

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I've install **grunt** and **grunt-cli** globally and locally in my project `root`, but I'm receiving this `error`:

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c\Users\computerName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt'

Why's it duplicated the `C:\` path and how can i change this problem?

Thanks in advance!